# With UIPanGestureRecognizer UINavigationController swipe to back is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when creating `cell` I also added `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to `cell` and implements all its handling according to requirement.

And this `Tableview` is contained in `myViewController` which is contained in `UINavigationController`.

With `UIPanGestureRecognizer` `UINavigationController` swipe to back is not working.

How can I do that when user start to swipe from extreme left side of the phone it perform `UINavigationController swipe to back` not my cell pan gesture.

```
-(void)move:(PanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:self];
    NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    TableViewCell *swipedCell  = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
    CGRect cellRect = swipedCell.frame;

    if(location.x < 75) {
       ?????
    }

.
.
.
//my pan gesture required functionality
}


-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `requireGestureRecognizerToFail`.

call: `[yourPanGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer` in your viewController

or

```
[cell.gestureRecognizers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof UIGestureRecognizer * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
            [obj requireGestureRecognizerToFail:interactivePopGestureRecognizer];
        }
    }];
```